# Followers of a user and ids of last 2 comments liked by each follower(if any), also the count of follower's followers, using mysql

Tags: mysql, social-networking

I have social application let's say like twitter, where user can follow other users and can likes some comments.

What I need to fetch is followers of a user and ids of last 2 comments liked by each follower(if any), also the count of follower's followers, using MySQL.

Here are the tables

Table **user_follower**

```
User_id  follower_id
1          2
2          3
1          5
1          6
1          7
```

Table **user_likes**

```
comment_id User_id date
41          2      some_date
42          2      some_date
41          5      some_date
42          5      some_date
43          5      some_date
43          2      some_date
43          6      some_date
```

how can we do this in a single mysql query?

so far i am able to get the followers and count of follower's follower and following both.

```
select uf.follower_id, 
(select count(*) from  user_followers uf1 where uf1.follower_id = uf.follower_id) as following_count,
(select count(*) from  user_followers uf2 where uf2.user_id = uf.follower_id) as follower_count,
from user_followers uf 
join users u on u.id = uf.follower_id
where uf.user_id = 1
```

what i want is now to get the 2 latest comment_ids for each follower, i.e. uf.follower_id here.
if not possible in the same query,
i am fine even with another query as will passing the follower_ids as in parameter, but it should give me 2 latest comment for each passed id..

Comment: Joe Celko's excellent book *SQL For Smarties* is full of examples of SQL for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: i just edited the post and added my query. i am also half done. but can figure out the way to get the comment ids/

Comment: @noka If you have found your answer in another site, please add it here as an answer and accept it. This would help others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. I have not tested it so it may have some syntax errors. Given the level of nesting used in this query I suspect it will perform badly with a very large dataset.

```
SELECT follower_id, num_followers, GROUP_CONCAT(comment_id)
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
        @r := IF(@g = t.follower_id, @r+1, 1) RowNum,
        @g := t.follower_id
    FROM (select @g:=null) AS initvars
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT followers.*, ul.comment_id
        FROM (
            SELECT
                uf1.user_id,
                uf1.follower_id,
                COUNT(uf2.follower_id) AS num_followers
            FROM user_follower uf1
            LEFT JOIN user_follower uf2
                ON uf1.follower_id = uf2.user_id
            WHERE uf1.user_id = 1
            GROUP BY uf1.user_id, uf1.follower_id
        ) AS followers
        LEFT JOIN user_likes ul
            ON followers.follower_id = ul.user_id
        ORDER BY followers.follower_id ASC, comment_id DESC
    ) AS t
) AS final
WHERE RowNum < 3
GROUP BY follower_id, num_followers;
```

**UPDATE** Here is the other query using the inequality join -

```
SELECT tmp.follower_id, COUNT(uf2.follower_id) AS num_followers, tmp.comments
FROM (
    SELECT follower_id, GROUP_CONCAT(comment_id ORDER BY comment_id DESC) AS comments
    FROM (
        SELECT uf.follower_id, ul1.*
        FROM user_follower uf
        LEFT JOIN user_likes ul1
            ON uf.follower_id = ul1.user_id
        LEFT JOIN user_likes ul2
            ON uf.follower_id = ul2.user_id
            AND ul1.comment_id < ul2.comment_id
        WHERE uf.user_id = 1
        GROUP BY ul1.user_id, ul1.comment_id
        HAVING COUNT(ul2.comment_id) < 2
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY tmp.follower_id
) AS tmp
LEFT JOIN user_follower uf2
    ON tmp.follower_id = uf2.user_id
GROUP BY tmp.follower_id
```

Comment: yups, its getting damn slow for me. but thanks for your efforts. i think it is better to go with another query. so my only problem left is to find latest 2 comments for each user given the userids.

Comment: here is a great link and i found my answer pretty quickly from this.http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104  search Within-group quotas (Top N per group)

Comment: I initially wrote a query using the INEQUALITY JOIN method but it performed badly with my test dataset. I will post it here when I find it. How many records do you have in each of your tables? What is the average number of likes per user? What is the average number of followers per user? I will try to produce a realistic distribution in my test data.

Comment: @nnicholas, thanks for your help, i will have on average arnd 200 followers and likes cold be arnd 500 or so. however i have broken the query in 2 parts now, first find all followers and then their likes

Comment: What indices do you have on these tables? It may help if you add the results of `SHOW INDEXES` to your original question.